# After installing VirtualBox to Fedora 17 the system won't boot (NVidia drivers)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, drivers, nvidia

My luck I had couple of older kernels, which work. The new kernel, probably somehow patched by VirtualBox fails to load. What fails is X-server, when it tries to start, here's the log:

```
[    14.284] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    14.284] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    14.285] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    14.285]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.285]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    14.294] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    14.294] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    14.294] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    14.294] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    14.294] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    14.294] (EE) No drivers available.
[    14.294] 
Fatal server error:
[    14.294] no screens found
```

Probably, I could just uninstall VirtualBox, then upgrade the kernel + NVidia drivers (oh god why...) and I'd get my laptop back to normal, however, this will mean no VirtualBox for me.

The question thus: is there any way to make friends between VirtualBox and NVidia? Perhaps I need some specific drivers for VirtualBox?

---

**EDIT**

(I'm the author of the question, but due to some errors happening in account management, I no longer appear as such)

Below is what I could get from `dmesg` but it's as terse as the note above:

```
[   14.058801] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   14.058807] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   14.172337] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
[   14.172636] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[   14.172888] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[   14.173166] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[   14.175252] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   14.175527] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.54  Sat Sep 29 00:05:49 PDT 2012
```

I will also look now into yum logs to see if there maybe was a record of what exactly did it do to the kernel / configuration.

---

**EDIT2**

```
Jul 26 00:53:18 Installed: kmod-VirtualBox-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64-4.2.12-1.fc17.13.x86_64
Jul 26 00:53:19 Installed: kmod-VirtualBox-4.2.12-1.fc17.13.x86_64
Jul 26 00:53:25 Installed: VirtualBox-4.2.12-1.fc17.x86_64
Jul 26 00:53:25 Erased: 1:kmod-nvidia-3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64-304.51-1.fc17.x86_64
```

OK, so, apparently, `yum` decided it needs to erase the NVidia kernel module... Is my guess correct then, that these two are incompatible? And if so, there is no way they will work together? What would be an alternative, if any to VirtualBox?

---

Sorry, I cannot comment yet. Just to make it clear: the driver is for the host system, not the guest. I actually took courage to just remove all things related to NVidia, reinstall them and VirtualBox started allright. What I did would be something along the lines of:

```
# yum update kernel* selinux-policy*
# yum list installed | grep nvidia | yum remove
# reboot
# yum install akmod-nvidia nvidia-settings nvidia-xconfig
```

I think I had CUDA drivers (used for development for NVidia paralleling technology), but I didn't use them anyway.

Comment: `[    14.294] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    14.294] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.`  Does the log say anything?

Comment: VMWare virtual machines need a different driver, so I suspect VirtualBox would need it's own driver as well. The Nvidia driver is not suitable for either situation.

Comment: Have you tried the akmod versions of virtualbox and nvidia?

Comment: Hey, @Kojotak well, in the very end of things, I've reinstalled akmod from `cuda` package (provided by NVidia), while keeping the drivers from `rpmfusion` with some manual tinkering in the rest of the `cuda` packages, but I wouldn't dare to put that as an answer / it's too complicated and I doubt that's a good way to solve things. I just got it "working somehow" and am happy with it for now.